# SPD 2010 workflow email based on value

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-alert-templates

I have a list that tracks the number of devices based on status by using a lookup "count" column. To this end, I know how many units I have left in inventory by the number of units with the "unassigned" status.

I would like to set up an alert that sends an email when the number of unassigned units is below a certain point, so that I know to reorder more.

I'm fairly new to SharePoint, so the farthest I got is:

**Step 1**

```
If CurrentItem:Status equals Unassigned

Calculate CurrentItem:Number of Units divided by 2 (Output to Variable: availableUnits )
```

(Units are paired, so I'm really interested in half of the value here.)

**Step 2**

```
If Variable:availableUnits is less than 10

Email users
```

This appears to work great when I start the workflow manually, but I don't know how to make it start on its own. I have the "when an item is created" and "changed" options selected in addition to allowing the workflow to be manually started, but if I try changing device statuses in order to change that number, no email is sent.

I need this workflow to either run weekly, or to run every time the number of unassigned devices changes.

Answer (score 0):

if "Number of Units" is your lookup "count" column (via count related),
then you don't get a number but a SPFieldLookupValue, so the comparsion step 2 doesn't work.

Also check if your other mails work on the server, 
had this happen to me.

Comment: Is there any way I can reference that number in my workflow? I know there's an easier way around this with 2013, but I don't expect we'll be upgrading any time soon.

Comment: I tried different steps; now I can get the workflow to work if I start it manually, but I can't get it to go automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

I created a second workflow that starts when an item on my master list is changed, wherein if the status is **not** unassigned (in which I've likely just assigned one somehow), it updates a column on my availability list. That in turn prompts my "low stock" alert workflow.

There are probably ways to refine the process, but for now, it works.